# Format computer without reinstalling Windows

Tags: windows, formatting

Someone trying to get rid of an old Windows 7 computer, but avoiding leaving personal information on it.

She does not have a valid Windows license nor an install disk (and as far as I know, no recovery partition). She does not care about having Windows on the disk since she plans to discard the computer.

Is there an easy way (I'm not next to her and she's not techy) for her to simply wipe the computer clean?

Comment: Sometimes there is an option in the BIOS to do this. It may be called something like Disk sanatizer. See if you can find a user manual for the computer on the manufacturer's website.

Comment: It’s not a branded computer.

Comment: I think it would depend on your definition of easy. There are lots of choices in utilities for erasing a disk. Google "disk wipe utilities". What I would do is temporarily remove the disk, install it as a secondary disk in another machine, and then use one of these disk wipe utilities to wipe it clean. That may not fit your definition of "easy", I don't know. But generally speaking, you cant boot from a disk and then wipe that same disk,  you would need to move it to another machine.  Another option might be to destroy the disk, drill holes in it, etc...

Comment: If the user is going to discard the computer to recycle (what you posted above), remove the drive and drill several holes in the drive, and then include the drive in the recycle.

Comment: Yeah, I don’t think any solution that would involve actually opening the machine would work ...

Comment: What about one of those? https://neosmart.net/wiki/restore-to-factory-settings/#Restore_without_installation_CDDVD-2